# Asp.Net - EF - MVC - Indexing Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using `Asp.Net` , `EF6` ( `MVC` )  and have some data stored in my view. What I need is some indexing for each row. Here is the view.

[image]

For every row I have 0 Index. I wanna know, if there is some Built in feature in EF, that will help to add indexes for each row, **(1,2,3....)**  and which will be automatically be updated, when new rows are created or deleted.

This is the Code for creating the table and doing Paging in my View.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    
        <div class="table-responsive"> 
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                            Index
                        </th>
                        <th style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                            @Html.ActionLink("English", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.EnglishSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        </th>
                        <th style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Russian", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RussianSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        </th>
                        <th style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Armenian", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ArmenianSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        </th>
                        <th style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                            @Html.ActionLink("French", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FrenchSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        </th>
                        <th style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Spanish", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SpanishSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        </th>
                        <th style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Arabic", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ArabicSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        </th>

                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    @{

                    foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
                    {
                        <tr class="clickableRow">
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle; font-size:medium;font-style:italic;" class="text-center">
                                @ViewBag.IndexOfRow.ToInt32
                            </td>
                            
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.English)
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Russian)
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Armenian)
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.French)
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Spanish)
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arabic)
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="text-center">
                                <span style="color:white;">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Text, @style = "color:red;" })
                                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Text })*@
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Text })
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                        }
                </table>
            </div>                                
                <br />
                Page @(Model.Item1.PageCount < Model.Item1.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Item1.PageNumber) of @Model.Item1.PageCount

                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Item1, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
            </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the code from my Controller

```
public ViewResult Index(int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 15;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var allModels = new Tuple<IPagedList<Translation>, List<Translation>>
            (translations.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize), translations.ToList()) { };


        return View(allModels);
    }
```

I have removed the unnecessary code, only is left the code for paging.

I have not done anything so far, because I have not find any indexing question or article in **Google** or **SO** so far.

Thanks for help.

Comment: that's row number in the UI, just loop the `i` variable somewhere (either when retrieving the data or when creating the table)

Comment: what is the row number @YuliamChandra ?

Comment: it's the `tr` index, what is your PK data type? why not just use identity number ? you need to also show how you retrieve the data

Comment: You also need to show how you create the table and how you do the paging in the action method

Comment: I will edit the Post now.

Comment: You can see it now @YuliamChandra.

Comment: this would make ALOT more sense if you were indexing the rows on the server side instead of trying to index them on the client side....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the start row index in the action method to `ViewBag`.

```
int pageSize = 15;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
ViewBag.StartRowIndex = ((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
```

Then use it in the view.

```
@{
   var rowIndex = (int)ViewBag.StartRowIndex;
}
foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
{
    <tr class="clickableRow">
        <td style="vertical-align:middle; font-size:medium;font-style:italic;" class="text-center">
            @(rowIndex++) //@ViewBag.IndexOfRow.ToInt32
        </td>
```

Comment: This was really amazing ! :) Thanks a lot. It works as expected .

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to put Index while creating table, you can loop like this in your table body:

```
<tbody>
 @{         
     int counter = 1;// Index start value
      foreach (var Item in Model.SomeList)
      {
          <tr>
           <td> @counter </td>
           </tr>
        counter++;
      }
  } 
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pawan, but every time the page is changing, the indexing starts over from 1 ..

Comment: yes, it will start from 1 whenever table is rendered. It will create a serial number starting from 1.

Comment: Is there a way to make it continuously looping for every page ?

Comment: I think you have to put this code inside every table body where you want a serial number column.

Comment: I am looping once in my view looping through all items of Model. :/

Answer (score 1):

When you dont know what to do, create a new class :))

Im kidding, but the idea remains valid.

Why dont you craete a new class that will represent your "ViewModel" that will have the exact EF model inside and an extra Index property that you will use to bind to an index in the view?

What you will pass from your controller to the view will be the new ViewModel class.

Note:

If you want to go fancy, you could go somewhere on the line of : ObservableCollection  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx which derrives from INotifyPropertyChanged

Basically it means that you have an event at your disposal that you can fire when the list has changed (add, delete) that will  be used to update the index.